# CSS styling the 2nd nested div inside of a parent div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

I have some nested divs to use as an alert box.  I'd like to use one class on the parent div to drive the styles for the divs inside of that.

```
<div class='aa-callout aa-prime'>
  <div class='row p-1 h-100'>
    <div class='col-1 d-flex align-items-center'>
      <i class="fal fa-exclamation-circle fa-3x text-white mx-auto"></i>
    </div>  
    <div class='col-11'>
      <h4>Blue is for information</h4>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde.</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I need to get the div containing the <i class=" section to have a background color and some other styles.  I've tried

```
.aa-prime > div:nth-child(2) {
```

and

```
.aa-prime div:nth-child(2) {
```

but neither applies the styles to the smaller div on the left with the fa-icon in it (namely background color and rounding of the left edges)

```
.aa-callout {
  max-width:100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
}
.aa-prime > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #036A96!important;
}
.aa-prime h4 {
  color:#036A96!important;
}
```

Comment: Hi:) The inner divs also have classes, why don't you use them instead of accessing them just as divs.

Comment: Why not simply `.aa-prime > div > div:first-child`?

Comment: @Azu - these are dynamic and we wanted to apply one class to the parent and have everything else fall into place.

Comment: @j08691 - thanks - very similar to the solution I went with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that structure is fixed (i.e. non-dynamic), you can use this selector:

```
.aa-prime > div:first-child > div:first-child { ...
```

(Note: `:nth-child(2)` won't work because the second `div` is a child of the first `div`)

Comment: thank you!  Also for the explanation that clearly says why the nth-child(2) won't work.